# How to restore data on the partition installed Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, partitioning, restore

On my laptop, I have a NTFS partition to contain my data. 
I decide to use Ubuntu 15.04. During the installation, I've made a big mistake, I've chosen the DATA partition instead of the partition reserved for Ubuntu root to install Ubuntu. And now, I lost all my important data.

I would like to know whether we can restore the data on a partition which is installed Ubuntu on.

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: Add output of sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3fdb698a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      411647      204800   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          411648    61439999    30514176   83  Linux
/dev/sda4        61442046   488394751   213476353    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       180228096   231428095    25600000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       231430144   282630143    25600000   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       282632192   488394751   102881280   83  Linux
/dev/sda8        61444096   110596095    24576000   83  Linux*
```

The partition on which contains my data is /dev/sda7

Comment: out put of `sudo fdisk -l` and what partition did you have your data on.

Answer (score 0):

To recover data or restore a partition. you will want to use testdisk. This may not work it may work but give it a go.

I am assuming the data DATA partition is still NTFS.

Boot in to a live DVD/USB you will need another storage device to put your data on.

When you are booted into the live install. Open up a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> and type in

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

make sure the partition is unmounted

Then type in terminal

```
sudo testdisk
```

Comment: Tks for helping me! I'm waiting for my new extern hdd. And then give it a try. Indeed my problem is: I have a NTFS partition named DATA  which contains my data. Now, I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on this partition (My mistake is here). So it is not anymore a NTFS.

Comment: testdisk finds lost partitions so if your NTFS it still there it might find it.